# How to set/get express session data using retrofit

Tags: android, node.js, retrofit, express-session

I am trying to add items into my cart that is stored in the express-session from an android application using retrofit. But the cart quantity remains the same. How do I set the header to access express session?

I am developing an e-commerce application using Nodejs for the backend and I am storing the cart on express-session. As for the client(Android app), I'm using retrofit to get the API data. Items were successfully added when I test the route using postman. But when I try using retrofit and set items through that, the quantity is always 1. I believe the reason is that the session is not being set.

I don't think it's necessary to create a new data store on the client: since session data are stored on the server side. But express-session id is stored in the cookie and if I am correct, cookies are stored on the client side. If this is a wrong approach, what would you suggest? and if it isn't, what is my mistake?

cart model - cart.js

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCrart) {
  this.items = oldCrart.items || {}; //if oldcart is not diggined use empity as default
  this.totalQty = oldCrart.totalQty || 0;
  this.totalPrice = oldCrart.totalPrice || 0;

  this.add = function(item, id) {
    var storedItem = this.items[id];
    if (!storedItem) {
      storedItem = this.items[id] = { item: item, qty: 0, price: 0 };
    }
    storedItem.qty++;
    storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
    this.totalQty++;
    this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price * 1; //*1 is there to treat the variable as intiger
  };
  this.generateArray = function() {
    var arr = [];
    for (var id in this.items) {
      arr.push(this.items[id]);
    }
    return arr;
  };
};
```

ProductDetails.java

```
  compositeDisposable.add(ClientApi.addToCart(Productid, "session Id")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        new Consumer<Cart>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Cart cart) throws Exception {
                                Toast.makeText(SingleProduct.this, "Product added to cart"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                Toast.makeText(SingleProduct.this,throwable.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }));
    }
```

Client api

```
    @GET("/mobile-api/add-to-cart/{id}")
    Observable<Cart> addToCart(@Path("id")String pid, @Header("cookie.connect.sid") String sid);
```

addToCart route

```
//serverside 
router.get("/mobile-api/add-to-cart/:id", function(req, res) {
  var productId = req.params.id;
  var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {}); //pass the cart if it exist or empity if it doesnt
  console.log("cart", cart);
  Product.findById(productId, function(err, product) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    cart.add(product, product.id);
    const totalQty = (req.session.cart = cart);

    var Mycart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    const cartData = {
      products: Mycart.generateArray(),
      totalPrice: Mycart.totalPrice
    };
     console.log(cart);//LOG THE CART
    res.json(cartData);
  });
});
```

I have added the same product four times using postman and the android app
Postman returned

```
cart Cart {
  items: 
   { '5c871fa5a9f2e1fc0ec63eaa': { item: [Object], qty: 4, price: 18220 } },
  totalQty: 4,
  totalPrice: 18220
```

to the console, but the android app returned

```
cart Cart {
  items: 
   { '5c871fa5a9f2e1fc0ec63eaa': 
      { item: { manufacture: [ { _id: 5c871fa5a9f2e1fc0ec63eab, manufacturer: 'toothless' } ],

  stokeamount: 3,
  image: 'some-image.jpg',
  price: '4555',
  pname: 'Wood crafted phone case',
  _id: 5c871fa5a9f2e1fc0ec63eaa },
        qty: 1,
        price: 4555 } },
  totalQty: 1,//TOTAL QUANTITY IS ALWAYS THE SAME
  totalPrice: 4555
```

The totalQty and qty is always 1

Comment: hey, did you solve this?

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. Check out the answer bellow. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I enabled my RetrofitClient class to accept cookies and it worked like a charm

```
     public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit instance;

    public static Retrofit getInstance(){
        //create OKHTTPCLIENT
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        CookieHandler cookieHandler = new CookieManager();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
                .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler))
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        if(instance == null)
            instance= new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.44.125:5000")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone use Fast Android Networking, follow this
: https://amitshekhar.me/Fast-Android-Networking/cookie.html